# Renting Airbnb. One set of keys Bucharest

Tags: bookings, safety, romania, rental, airbnb

We are 3 adults. We were given only one set of keys. The owner wants to keep the second set of keys. Are there Airbnb rules regardingthis situation?

Our schedules are different. The time we leave the apartment also is different. Some of us would like to stay at the apartment, but if one pair of keys is available it is under great risk to leave somebody without the possibility to leave the apartment, because he is locked in it.

The owner of the apartment can’t share another pair of keys. It is a big issue and an uncomfortable and unsafe situation. What to do?

I’m nervous and feel unhappy and frustrated when one of us is left locked in the apartment without the possibility to leave the apartment. It is a big problem. Thank you.

Comment: When your question is closed do not ask again!!!!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is a duplicate of an unanswered/closed question and has the same problems as the closed one, should have been closed instead of answered.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151426/discussion-on-question-by-arabica-renting-airbnb-one-set-of-keys-bucharest); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't think there any obligation for the host to provide more than one set of keys (unless they said otherwise in the description or in previous exchanges), for a long term rental it seems to me the owner should be able to make the effort to get you a duplicate.

If they are actually the owner (and not a tenant who is subletting the flat on Airbnb), they should have the ability to get a duplicate. Some keys have an associated card that they need to show to get a duplicate, or there may be some other procedure like providing evidence that they are the owner of the place. I'm not aware of any keys that just cannot be duplicated at all, there are just a few hoops to jump through for them of them.

In the worst case they should be able to change the lock and get multiple keys. This is often the simplest and quickest option, and not necessarily the most expensive (in any modern lock, you just have to change the cylinder, that takes a few minutes. See https://youtu.be/15XJxa4XVWU for an example). A seemingly decent lock cylinder with 5 keys can be bought for less than 20 euros on Amazon!

[image]

Whatever the option, there will be a cost for that, which can range from a few euros to a few hundred euros, and it may take some time in some cases, but that would make you and future guests a lot more happy, so the host should be able to accommodate that.

Honestly I think I would go for the cylinder change option, that's probably the fastest and quickest, they just need to find out the size of the existing one before ordering a new one.

Worst case, you could even do it yourself (and either change it back when you leave or just give him one of the keys), though that could get you in trouble with the host if they don't agree for whatever reason. **You most definitely need approval from the host before you do that.**

The alternative is to use a lockbox. Some lockboxes like this one:

[image]

need to be affixed to a wall, others like this one:

[image]

can be attached a bit like a bike lock to all sorts of places. I know in some cities I have visited where there are lots of AirBnbs you see dozens of them attached to bike racks, poles, barriers, etc. Here's a real-life example, the bike rack on the left as two such lockboxes:

[image]

In some cities or neighbourhoods finding a place to attach such a lockbox is extremely easy. In others it may be a lot more difficult, though (sadly, the few random places I checked out in Bucharest seem to fall in the latter category). Avoid attaching to private properties (other than the one where the flat is, and then only if the owner says it's OK).

Just make sure the city does not have a policy to remove them (may happen in places where there are just too many and/or there is a war between the city and AirBnb). But that will require the person remaining in the flat to close the door after other people leave, and put it in the lockbox when the last one leaves (and vice versa), which is impractical if you have conflicting sleep periods.

Yet another alternative would be to find a nearby shop with the right opening hours who would be willing to hold on to the key for you, but that can quickly get into a can of worms.

Comment: Thank you. Your attention is truly touched and I appreciate greatly for your kind advice. There is a lock box but it is no place where to adjust it. Also I found the information that it is not safely. Thank you again

Comment: Changing the lock cylinder on a rented apartment? Are you serious? That's the quickest way to get into a lot of trouble, if the owner finds out (which is quite likely). Getting a duplicate key is much safer.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko What I mean through most of that discussion is having the host do that. As I said, the guests could do it themselves, but they would need approval of the host. Edited to make that clearer.

Comment: I mean I need the lock box should be anchored  in a secure location

Answer (score 2):

Go to a locksmith and make copies of the keys for your own use.  Then throw away the keys when you leave, or give them to the landlord.

Comment: The owner said it's impossible to copy the key. And the key says do not duplicate. 
Thank you already tried

Comment: They brought a lock box but there is no place where to adjust the box. Thank you

Comment: And I afraid to leave the key and it is not useful and doesn’t resolve the issue with one key.

Comment: In many countries it is illegal to make a copy of keys of a house/apartment you do not own (without having a permission). And you and the locksmith get share of responsibility if something happen on the apartment (unless you can prove 100% that your copies were not involved on it).  So too risky. Do not do it.

Comment: @Arabica why would you need to "adjust the box"?

Comment: I mean I need the lock box should be anchored  in a secure location